# Segmentation fault after fopen inside a function. No issues when doing fopen in main,

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C. The goal of the function Foo is to accept a string, change up some of it's characters and see if there is a file with that name. If such a file exists, print it's contents on STDOUT.

Sounds pretty simple and it should be, however I keep getting segmentation fault when I call fopen inside the Foo function. I guess I am doing something bad with the memory, but I can't figure out what it is.

Here is the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Foo(const char* fname);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    Foo("a.c");
    return 0;
}


void Foo(const char* fname)
{
    size_t len = strlen(fname);
    printf("size is %i", (int)len);
    char* fname_hash;
    strcpy(fname_hash, fname);

    int i;
    //"escape" some of the characters
    for(i =0; i < len; i++){
        if( fname_hash[i] == '/' 
            || fname_hash[i] == '.' 
            || fname_hash[i] == '&'
            || fname_hash[i] == ' '
            || fname_hash[i] == '_'){
            fname_hash[i] = '_';
        }
    }

    if( access( fname_hash, F_OK ) != -1 ) {
        printf("File exists\n");
        FILE* fp = fopen ( fname_hash , "r" );
        if( !fp ) perror(fname_hash),exit(1);

        fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
        long lSize = ftell( fp );
        rewind( fp );

        char* buffer = calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
        if( !buffer ) fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);

        if( 1!=fread( buffer , lSize, 1 , fp) )
              fclose(fp),free(buffer),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);

        printf("%s", buffer); 

        fclose(fp);
        free(buffer);
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Really don't write this `if( !fp ) perror(fname_hash),exit(1);` just use braces and blocks.

Comment: Okay, I will change this.

Comment: `strcpy(fname_hash, fname);`. You need to allocate buffer memory for `fname_hash` first.

Comment: char* fname_hash;
    strcpy(fname_hash, fname);

this is problematic, where do you copy fname to? Somewhere undefined. Either use malloc or a fixed buffer array for fname_hash variable. Or use `strdup`.

Comment: You're copying to fname_hash yet the pointer is uninitialized, you have to allocate space and have fname_hash point to it. Instead of strcpy, use strdup which automatically allocates memory and copies the string into the newly allocated memory and returns a pointer to the duplicate string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
char* fname_hash;
strcpy(fname_hash, fname)
```

is a serious problem.

`char* fname_hash` merely makes space on the stack for a pointer to a string or some characters.  It *doesn't* allocate any space for a string, and it doesn't set the pointer to point anywhere (it will have a random value).

The subsequent `strcpy`, then copies fname to that random location, which is almost inevitably a disaster, albeit it might be a disaster waiting to happen, when the implications of overwriting a random bit of memory become clear later in the execution of the code.

You either need to use malloc to allocate some space (and remember to clear it up later) or you need to do something like:

```
char fname_hash[100];
```

instead, but you have to think about what the '100' number should really be, and you should think about what happens if fname is longer than the space you've reserved.

A reasonable rule of thumb for string handling in 'c' is that if the code looks simple and merely seems to be doing what you want using basic standard library functions, then it is actually completely wrong and full of hazards.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: Be aware that, as Will Dean I'm sure knows, using a magic number allocation of 100 is really dangerous.  You will want to be sure that you have an array at least as large as the input.

Comment: Even simpler, `strdup()` is [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) in POSIX environments:  `char *fname_hash = strdup(fname); ... free(fname_hash);`

Comment: @DavidHoelzer - Definitely - I did try to cover that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may have other problems, but your segmentation fault is likely being caused by this:

```
char* fname_hash;
strcpy(fname_hash, fname);
```

Here you create a pointer `fname_hash` and then try to copy data to the memory location it points to but you have neither initialized it nor have you allocated memory for it.

```
char * fname_hash;
fname_hash = malloc(len+1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(fname_hash, fname);
```

This should resolve that problem, though you should note that this still isn't "safe."  I leave it to you to research `malloc` and add a check to verify that the memory allocation has succeeded.

Comment: Isn't it better for him to use strdup as it'll simply take care of the allocating and copying of the new string?

Comment: I don't know about better, but that's a good approach.  I was trying not to modify his code much and introduce too many concepts at once.  Pedagogically I think it's pretty important that he learn how to allocate memory with `malloc`

Comment: Pedagogically yes it's important however for the purpose of this code strdup would simplify it. I'd say he isn't familiar with the concept of allocating memory since he couldn't understand the segmentation fault but he is familiar with function calling.

Comment: You could certainly post an answer to that effect.